# Unable to see Event Grid System Topic on storage account

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I have created a storage account and created some event subscriptions for it as well. But in the 'Events' tab of the storage account I can't see the system topic, and I'm also getting no events delivered, even though the event subscriptions are visible. I can see the system topic is created fine, and it has the correct source and event subscriptions, but nothing is going through. My trigger is set to BlobCreated and blobs are continuously being created in the storage account. Why could this happen? Are there any diagnostic logs I could figure out from?

A similar setup has worked for me in other environments. Is this an Azure China specific issue maybe? I have already tried recreating the system topic and subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

> *Event grid System topics, event subscriptions & Azure events are location constraint as detailed in* [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/system-topics#location-and-resource-group-for-a-system-topic).

*To avoid these types of issues, make sure that you are creating everything in the same region.*

*I created all of those in the same region (East US), and I was able to capture all of the event system topic and subscription information under the same storage account as follows:*

`Storage account -> Events`:

[image]

[image]

*You need to add your delivery properties as per requirements (Here I set it for storage queues)*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting the effort of going through documentation, but in my case we're using a premium account, and Microsoft support has acknowledged there is an issue, we're working with them. Thanks!